# Lock a user with his home folder

Tags: filesystems, users, home, sandbox

Is there any way of making a user only able to see and modificate his home folder? I am currently on arch linux.

Just explaining a little better, the user would not be able to see  `/etc` or any other system directories or folders from others

Comment: And what can the user do with that system? He can't access any binaries (probably not even the shell). Usually it's sufficient to prevent *writing* in other directories except their home directory. That having said you can look at `chroot`ing the user to their home directory and possibly provide some binaries.

Comment: POSIX ACL can do this neatly, and it should be supported on most modern Linux distros / filesystems. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists for general usage.

Comment: For example, for user 'naughty', you will want to use `setfacl -m user:naughty:--- -R /; setfacl -R -x user:naughty:rwx /home/naughty`. Additional changes are of course needed or he won't even get his login shell running.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'll make some search and get it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot usefully restrict interactive access to the system directories such as `/etc` further than is already provided.

You can prevent a user from accessing anyone else's home folder simply by reducing the permissions on all home folders.

For example, if all users have their home directories under `/home` then this command will lock the access rights down tightly

```
chmod go= /home/*
```

Don't forget that it needs to be run as the `root` user.